# Detecting semi-duplicate records in Bash/AWK

Tags: bash, awk

Right now I have a script that rifles through tabulated data for cross-referencing record by record (using AWK).  But I've run into a problem. AWK is great for line-by-line comparisons to run through formatted data, but I also want to detect semi-duplicate records. Unfortunately, `uniq` will not work by itself as the record is not 100% carbon-copy.

This is an orderly list, sorted by second and third columns.  What I want to detect is the same values in Column 3, 6 and 7

Here's an example:

```
JJ   0072  0128  V7589  N     22.35   22.35   0.00   Auth
JJ   0073  0128  V7589  N     22.35   22.35   0.00   Auth
```

The second number is different while the other information is exactly the same, so `uniq` will not find it solo.

Is there something in AWK that lets me reference the previous line?  I already have this code block from AWK going line-by-line. (**EDIT** awk statement was an older version that was terrible)

```
awk '{printf "%s", $0; if($6 != $7 && $9 != "Void" && $5 == "N") {printf "****\n"} else {printf "\n"}}' /tmp/verbout.txt
```

Comment: What do you want to do with all duplicate lines? Do you just want to keep the first line where `$3 $6 $7` are the same? The last one? Just mark it with `duplicate`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there something in AWK that lets me reference the previous line?

No, but there's nothing stopping you from *explicitly* saving certain info from the last line and using that later:

```
{
    if (last3 != $3 || last6 != $6 || last7 != $7) {
        print
    } else
        handle duplicate here
    }
    last3=$3
    last6=$6
    last7=$7
}
```

The `lastN` variables all (effectively) default to an empty string at the start then we just compare each line with those and print that line if any are different.

Then we store the fields from that line to use for the next.

---

That is, of course, assuming duplicates should only be detected if they're consecutive. If you want to remove duplicates when order doesn't matter, you can `sort` on those fields first.

If order needs to be maintained, you can use an associative array to store the fact that the key has been seen before, something like:

```
{
    seenkey = $3" "$6" "$7
    if (seen[seenkey] == 0) {
        print
        seen[seenkey] = 1
    } else {
        handle duplicate here
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution ended up working because of the order in the list. Thanks a bunch! What I ended up with was something like this `awk '{printf $0; if ((($6 != $7) || (last3 == $3 && last6 == $6 && last7 == $7 )) && $9 != "Void" && $5 == "N") {printf "****\n"} else {printf "\n"}; last3=$3; last6=$6; last7=$7;}' /tmp/verbout.txt`

Answer (score 0):

one way of doing this with `awk` is

```
$ awk '{print $0, (a[$3,$6,$7]++?"duplicate":"")' file
```

this will mark the duplicate records, note that you don't need to sort the file.

if you want to just print the uniq records, the idiomatic way is

```
$ awk '!a[$3,$6,$7]++' file
```

again, sorting is not required.